# Where can I find the meaning of exit codes? E.g. 1073740771

Tags: azure-webjobs

I wrote a web job application in VisualStudio, which already worked on Azure, but the latest uploaded version failed. The system error is: Job failed due to exit code -1073740771

The code can run locally.
Manually deployed on Azure: I upload a zip file with application, and setup.exe, and Application folder ...
AzureWebJobsDashboard , Connecting string is set of course.

Could someone tell me what exit code exactly means?

UPDATE: Probably this is a generic code. The cause of the error was uploaded file was incorrect. In VS2017 webjob deploy function doesn't work properly. Better way create a build, than manually zip all files under bin folder. After than upload it. That works.

Comment: Did you tried googling the code? I can see bunch of results with "azure error 1073740771"

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to 16 decimal number, -1073740771=0xC000 041D. And then search for this error code.